# PHP method to get values dynamically from an array object property

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

In this class, is it possible to get dynamically a value from the array?

```
class MyClass {

    private $array_data;

    function __construct() {
        $this->array_data['first']['a'] = '1';
        $this->array_data['second']['b'] = '2';
        $this->array_data['third']['c'] = '3';
    }

    public function getIndexValue($index){
        return $this->{'array_data' . $index};
    }
}

$MyClass = new MyClass();

// Prints NULL, but i expect '1'
var_dump($MyClass->getIndexValue("['first']['a']"));
```

Comment: Might as well just make `$array_data` public if you're just going to have a public accessor method anyway.

Comment: @Supericy, In my application i need to access this data via method

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP dynamic array index name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458241/php-dynamic-array-index-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. Rather than passing in a string for the indexes, you pass in an array.

```
public function getIndexValue(array $indexes) {
    // count the # of indexes we have
    $count = count($indexes);

    // local reference to data
    $data = $this->array_data;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        // enter the array at the current index
        $data = $data[$indexes[$i]];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

And then rather than a string, you'd pass in an array:

```
$MyClass->getIndexValue(['first', 'a'])
```