# How to create multiple array in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make multiple array by php (Laravel 5). There are two arrays as follows.

```
$tags=['en' =>[]];
$TAGS = ['test1','test2','test3',...]
```

I want to make this array as a return value in certain code like this:

```
return [
    'tags' => [
        'en' => [
            'test1' => 'test1',
            'test2' => 'test2',
            'test3' => 'test3',
            ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
return [
    'tags' => [
        'en' => [
            foreach($TAGS as $TT)
                array_push($tags['en'], $TT);
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: you can use the foreach and create a new array $en and then in the original array you can do 'en' => $en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP dynamic array index name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458241/php-dynamic-array-index-name)

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<?php
$mainArray = array("EN","IT","SP"....);
$returnArray = array();
foreach($mainArray as $key => $value){
    //Create the sub array here as you want it.
    $subArray = [
        "Test1" => "test1",
        "Test2" => "test2",
        "Test3" => "test3"
    ];        
    array_push($returnArray[$value],$subArray);
}

return $returnArray;
?>
```

Comment: reply thanks, I'msorry, "Only variables can be passed by reference error" occured.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$json = array();
$langs = ['en','fr'];
$tags = ['test1','test2','test3'];
 foreach ($langs as $lang) {
    $json[$lang] = [];
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $json[$lang][] = $tag;
    }
 }
return $json;
```